# Is it possible to manage logs through Obfuscation with yGuard?

Tags: java, yguard

I obfuscated a java web application and I ran into some trouble as below:

1. I have alot of uresolved external classes even though I have
   included in the ant build xml the external jar this way:

   ```
   <externalclasses>
     <pathelement location="${tomcatpath}/lib/"/>
     <pathelement location="${webinfdir}/lib/"/>
   </externalclasses
   ```
2. How can I manage logs to understand anything?
3. Can I also obfuscate the jsp files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found out the following:*

1. The jars must be put individually instead of their directories
2. The jsps and any configuration file must be put in the jar
3. The logs are to be recognized through yGuard GUI