# yguard not updating properties file in the jar

Tags: ant, yguard

I have jar file having some properties files in it like log4j.properties and config.properties.  Following is my ant script for yguard. Everything else is working but the properties file updation.

```
<target name="yguard">
    <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="lib/yguard.jar" />
    <yguard>
        <inoutpairs resources="none">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="MyApp.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <mapper type="glob" from="MyApp.jar" to="MyAppObs.jar" />
        </inoutpairs>
        <externalclasses>
            <pathelement location="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" />
        </externalclasses>
        <rename conservemanifest="true" mainclass="com.amit.Application" >
            <adjust replaceContent="true" >
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
            </adjust>
        </rename>
    </yguard>
</target>
```

**config.properties file**

```
com.amit.Application.param1 = something
```

I found some question in stackoverflow but they didn't help. One place it was mentioned that the file (like jsp, xml, properties) should be in the jar file which I already have. But my yguard obfuscated file just get the files copied as it is.

I tried many combinations with rename & adjust tags but nothing worked for me.

Following post I already visited

[Is it possible to manage logs through Obfuscation with yGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907212/is-it-possible-to-manage-logs-through-obfuscation-with-yguard)

[How to include obfuscated jar file into a war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983985/how-to-include-obfuscated-jar-file-into-a-war-file)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want yGuard to obfuscate the name of the field `param1`, because `com.amit.Application` is obviously your entry point and yGuard excludes the given main class automatically. So basically you want the outcome to be something like

```
com.amit.Application.AÖÜF = something
```

This isn't possible, because yGuard can only adjust class names in property files, as state here: [yGuard Manual](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#adjust)

Comment: Thanks Sabastian for the comments but I want yguard to replace the class name not the param name. The class name I mentioned was just a sample unfortunately I picked something resembling entry class but its  just some class other than main class.

Comment: then write it like this: com.amit.Application#param1 = something

Comment: I am not sure how this will help. Even if I just put the class name in that file it doesn't get replaced with obfuscated name. Any other suggestion?

Comment: No, because it works for me. I placed a properties file into my project, a class that gets obfuscated, then wrote something like com.MyClass#value = "hi" into the properties file, adjusted the build process like you did and it works.